# access php objects with properties

Tags: php, object

Google auth services return a php object (Lets call it $Ticket). It's value is this

```
Google_LoginTicket Object ( [envelope:Google_LoginTicket:private] => Array ( [alg] => RS256 [kid] => 057d4167ee9b75e7b3a3fcc9c1ca17a14dab5044 ) )
```

Now i want to access the value of alg, that is "RS256".

```
print_r ($Ticket->{'envelope:Google_LoginTicket:private'});
```

print_r doesn't give anything.

Comment: Have you tried doing `print_r($Ticket)`? Add the output to your question

Comment: @adam He posted it's value?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google_LoginTicket have getAttributes() function, which return array of attributes, you can check this, in source code
https://github.com/sylvainw/GPlusGlobe/blob/master/src/auth/Google_LoginTicket.php

```
$attrs = $Ticket->getAttributes();
print_r($attrs["envelope"]);
```

Comment: I would add, that Google_LoginTicket is private, so you can't directly access it. And it is bad habit to make any attribute public. One should always try to use getters/setters.

Comment: "envelope" is private ;) Google_LoginTicket is the class name

Answer (score 0):

You can access private properties through [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). However, it is not recommended. These are mostly features used by frameworks.

Instead, you should search for methods providing you with the value you are looking for.

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($Ticket));
```

Typically, reading the API documentation or the [source file directly](https://github.com/sylvainw/GPlusGlobe/blob/master/src/auth/Google_LoginTicket.php) will allow you to see the methods available on the class.

Answer (score 0):

The `envelope` instance variable is private, so you can't just access it like that; you have to work with the methods that are [provided](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/Google_LoginTicket.php#60):

```
$attributes = $Ticket->getAttributes();

$envelope = $attributes['envelope'];
```